# Can I move this outlet near another outlet on the interior of an exterior wall?

Tags: receptacle, code-compliance

I am renovating my bathroom vanity. There are two outlets above the sinks. This is the interior side of an exterior wall. The house is located in New Jersey. The two outlets are not on the same circuit.

The outlets are not placed symmetrically above the sinks. As a result, one outlet is above a sink and the other is to the side. To make space for tall mirrors and to make things symmetrical, I would like to move the outlets closer together.

There is a stud in the wall at the exact middle point between the two sinks. One box is mounted to the right side of that center-stud. I'd like to move the other box past the left-stud, and to the left side of the center-stud, allowing me to install two full-length mirrors above the sinks and also have things look symmetrical.

It seems that I will have to figure out how to get the wire through or past the existing stud and then mount the box on the other stud.

Is this allowed by code? I have replaced light switches and outlets, but I've never moved a box. Is it relatively easy to do or am I better off calling an electrician?

**Here is an image of the situation:**

[image]

**Here is an image of the inside of the box I'd like to move:**

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you can just close off the one box and replace the other one with another box with more receptacles?

Comment: Also, you should mention what state you're in to get a more accurate code answer.

Comment: @FrancisJohn that's my alternative if this doesn't work. The solution above would make things exactly symmetrical, which is nice.

Comment: Are these receptacles on the same circuit or two different circuits? For the receptacle you would like to move, open it up and let us know how many cables/wires are going into it and/or upload a picture.

Comment: Also both receptacles should be replaced with GFCI versions if they are not already.

Comment: You are doing all this with the wall insides exposed, right?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact: Updated. Please note that the picture has changed, I learned the left-stud is actually between the existing position of the box and the target position of the box.

Comment: @Armand: I am replacing both and they are currently GFCI. I don't know what or how I'm doing it, that's why I'm posting here. I imagine I will cut a big square of sheet rock away and give myself plenty of room to work if I can do the project.

Comment: That's one box picture. Assuming that's the one you want to move, it could be tricky. It has two cables - "line" and "load", so both cables need to reach to the new location - that may be "one easy, one hard/impossible", "both easy" or "both hard/impossible". Never truly impossible, but could be a lot of work. On the other hand, anything fed from the "load" wires is already protected by this GFCI and does not need a GFCI of its own. I'd also recommend replacing this GFCI - it looks rather old (lots of little clues).

Comment: One often-easier way to "move" an outlet is just to use the existing outlet to feed a new outlet in the desired location. However, the original outlet (or box) needs to be accessible for possible future work or repairs. Will your new mirror covering this location be hinged so that it could be swung out of the way for future access to the original outlet location?

Comment: One thing that no one has mentioned is that junction boxes cannot be buried; they must be accessible without using tools. Since you are putting a mirror over one of the old boxes, you cannot use it was a junction box. This means that either (1) the old wiring to the left box must already be long enough to reach the new box; (2) you can pull that wiring back to an unburied location for a junction box; (3) you can run new wiring to the new box or (4) you run both boxes off of the right circuit.

Comment: @DoxyLover  One way to get around that is to have the mirror on hinges.  OP can still use that box as a junction box to extend the cables.  With hinges can also make a cabinet behind the mirror.